# global variable in dll inconsistent?

Tags: c++, dll, mfc

I am creating a (temporary) log file from a dll. But the global variable I defined seem to be inconsistent.

Here is how I define variables in dll's main cpp file.

```
char * g_bfr;
__declspec(dllexport) CMemFile memFile;
```

Then in DllMain function:

```
extern "C" int APIENTRY
DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    // Remove this if you use lpReserved
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpReserved);

    if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        TRACE0("UTLADO.DLL Initializing!\n");

        g_bfr = new char[1000]();

        memFile.Attach((BYTE*)g_bfr, 1000 );

        // Extension DLL one-time initialization
        if (!AfxInitExtensionModule(AcnDll, hInstance))
            return 0;


        new CDynLinkLibrary(AcnDll);
    }
    else if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH)
    {
        TRACE0("UTLADO.DLL Terminating!\n");

        delete[] g_bfr;

        // Terminate the library before destructors are called
        AfxTermExtensionModule(AcnDll);
    }
    return 1;   // ok
}
```

The problem is when I use the memFile in the dll to write log to memory, somewhere down the road, it becomes bad as if newly declared (uninitialized). See the [image: snapshot] where file positions/size are all reset.

What makes thing weirder is when I set breakpoint in DllMain, inside `case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`, it never breaks there (like never called) but the initialization does work! Breakpoint in `case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` does work and is called only when I close application.

So, in a nutshell, it appears that `memFile` gets created another time during course of the application but should it? How can I make sure I only have one instance of the global variable in the dll?

Comment: Use a breakpoint on the close method or the destructor. You have the source of the MFC. I hope you are aware that this only works when you use a shared version of the MFC!

Answer (score 0):

After you have finished using the DLL, try using the FreeLibrary function.
However, this method has not been considered for concurrent use.

[enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/library/windows/desktop/ms686944(v=vs.85).aspx)